# Disable second textBox when I select second radio button in Laravel

Tags: forms, laravel

Hi all I want to disable second textBox when I select second radio button in Laravel. How to solve it?

```php
{{ Form::open()}}

    {{ Form::radio('oneway') }} Radio 1
    {{ Form::radio('roundway') }} Radio 2<br><br>
    Textbox 1: {{ Form::text('arrive', null) }}
    Textbox 2: {{ Form::text('depart', null) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using jquery or plain javascript. On the click event of radio 2 disable the second textbox. However you need to wrap that textbox in a div or span or whatever so you can hide it after they click the second radio button.

This cannot be done in plain laravel code.